# Using Android support toolbar with fragments not triggering onCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

The toolbar appears but no menu items.
If I move the code to the activity, the correspondent onCreateOptionsMenu is called.
If I go back to the actionbar the fragment version works fine.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imd_toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

}
```

because of this and the more complex lifecycle, I am thinking to go fragment-free (n00b here btw), plus I don't really plan on doing tablet special layout.
Still it bugs me that this has not happened to someone else, please let me know if this is known or just an issue from me.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have items added in your menu xml ??

Comment: Why are you using getActivity() in Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imd_toolbar);?

Comment: How you add items to your menu?

Comment: set the toolbar and menu in activity itself, just make them visible in that particular fragment.

Comment: sorry for the lack of info, everything was working fine until I have switched from actionbar to toolbar

Comment: @Michal_196 is the only way I have found to add the toolbar, and I do think the issue may lay there.

Comment: @himanshu1496 I thought of this, but I can't find a way to make it cleanly without having to deal with code specific for fragments in activities. Also, is this the way it was thought?

Comment: see it is simple, set your toolbar in activity and add your menu file (Keep visibility false). In Fragment override `onCreateOptionsMenu` make them visible.

Comment: @himanshu1496 ok I will try this in a bit. However, while in the end I will be pragmatic, I still wonder if this is a good way to do it and is this a bug or am I configuring something wrong?

Comment: @Pacho please see my answer.

Comment: @Pacho see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem.

Change this line:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imd_toolbar);
```

To something like this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imd_toolbar);
```

Example:

```
Toolbar toolbar;
private View rootView;


rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container, false);
toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tool_bar1);
```

The reason for the problem i believe is that  `getActivity()` in a Fragment returns the Activity the Fragment is currently associated with, not **view**.

Comment: Thanks! that was it, such noobness.

Answer (score 0):

Create your `menu` file something like below:

**sample_menu.xml**:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_sms_ticket"
    android:title="@string/menu_sms_ticket"
    android:visible="false"/>
</menu>
```

In your `activity` add this `menu` file and change your code for adding `toolbar`, do it inside your `activity`. In your `fragment`, call `setHasOptionMenu(true)` and override below function something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.getItem(0).setVisible(true);
}
```

Please try this let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is not really what I wanted though. I want to know how to make it work from the fragment without the activity knowing which toolbar I am using. This workaround of setting the toolbar in the activity (I don't really need to hide it and show it, just need the method to be called), will be something I will try if not able to make it work directly in fragment. And maybe, I will just get rid of the fragment.

Comment: Setting the `toolbar` in activity is not a work around, thats the usual way. And you are hiding the `menu item` in `activity` and showing it in the particular `fragment` where you want it. Using fragment make sense when you have similar parent layout behaviour and you want to update the part of  it multiple times. Anyway your call.

Comment: I see ok, thanks for your help, I am still learning android so maybe will end up implementing it that way. If works for me then I will come back and accept this answer.